Can't open a Git Bash terminal in VS Code (exit code 3221225786)
I am trying to open a Git Bash terminal in VS Code, but I am getting the following error:

Error:
The terminal process "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe '--login'" failed to launch(exit code: 3221225786)

How can I open a Bash terminal correctly?

On Visual Code docs, there is a page on troubleshooting terminal launch which has a subsection Terminal exits with code 3221225786 (or similar). Not sure if it is relevant to your case. By the way, the signed interpretation of 3221225786 is -1073741510 (in hex 0xC000013A).

This doesn't work for me.Please suggest
